# Why span disappears on mouseenter?

Tags: jquery

```
<DIV id=gallery2>
  <DIV class=center_content>
    <A id=example2 class=photo-link title=567 href="http://www.hdwallpapersarena.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Desktop-wallpaper-Free-honey-bee1.jpg" rel=group1 smoothbox?>
      <IMG id=mygal class=mygalclass src="http://www.hdwallpapersarena.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Desktop-wallpaper-Free-honey-bee1.jpg" width=132 height=137>
    </A>
  </DIV>
</DIV>
```

Hovering on the bee image shows me a `span` with links, but when I go and select the `span` it disappears, I guess it's because of the `mouseleave` event of the image.

here's a demo http://jsfiddle.net/sbYG4/13/

How can I tie the `Div`, `Image` and `Span` to the same `onmouseenter` and `mouseleave`?

Comment: Could you put an exemple on http://jsfiddle.net/ please ?

Comment: You need to post an example with the JavaScript, jsFiddle is a good tool to use for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use the div id to tie all in one so that whenever it enters that div all the span img etc gets effected and since you are using `anchor` tag and there is no specification of its `text-decoration` in css and set it to `none` plus you can use the `anchor` tag as `display:inline-block`so that it could take up a space and could act when `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave` occurs

use this it works (updated  again for multiple images)

```
$(".photo-link").on({

    mouseenter: function () {

 $(this).find('span').fadeIn('slow');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
 $(this).find('span').fadeOut('slow');
    }
});
```

plus removed that `display:none` from `A.delete` as the `span` already had it

Comment: Param Veer I used your suggestion but it does not work, I'm I missing something?
http://jsfiddle.net/sbYG4/38/

Comment: Thanks, I run into another problem. I'm doing this for a auto-generated image gallery in my website, where every image will have the same attributes (id,class). your code works but when I hover on another image, it hovers on all my images .........check this.....>   http://jsfiddle.net/sbYG4/53/

Comment: Thanks a lot Param, it worked out great, check it out       http://dataonpixels.com/gallery.php

Comment: happy to help friend :) well nice use of this code . just checked the link

Answer (score 0):

In response to your first question: we can't really tell, because we don't have the code for the events.

In response to you second question, give all 3 the same class, and attach the `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave` handlers to the class.

If you're using jQuery, it looks like this:

```
$('.theClassYouGaveThem').bind("mouseenter", function(){/*Code here */ });
```

and

```
$('.theClassYouGaveThem').bind("mouseleave", function(){/*Code here */ });
```

or if you want to do them both,

```
$('.theClassYouGaveThem').bind("mouseenter mouseleave", function(){/*Code here */ });
```